# How do I call the evernote struct object to report all notes inside a notebook?

Tags: ruby, evernote

I am working through the ruby evernote-thrift API and sandbox.

I am experiencing some issues interpreting the docs; I am trying to retrieve the subject line from all the notes inside a particular notebook.

To get the name of the notebook I call 
`notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks(authToken)` and then run `.each` on `notebooks`. According to the docs there is a struct object called `noteList` but I can’t figure out how to use it.

this is the link to the docs area I am trying to leverage http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/evernote-thrift/Evernote/EDAM/NoteStore/NoteList#struct_fields-instance_method

my attempt, is as follows, but its not returning anything. unfortunately im not familiar with structs at all.

```
notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks(authToken)

notebooks.each do |notebook|
  next if notebook.name != 'First Notebook'

  notes = notebook.noteList
  noteList.each do |note|
    puts note
  end
end
```

i am getting a no method error... which makese sense because its a struct I just dont know how to leverage it...

```
undefined method `noteList' for <Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook:0x007fb2041683f8> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated docs for our Ruby SDK are confusing (sorry!), but I find the general docs to be much clearer: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/.

As you can see in https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Notebook, the `Notebook` object does not have an attribute called `noteList`. There is a struct called `NoteList`, but that was what the removed `NoteStore.findNotes` returned.

The procedure for getting the titles/subjects of the notes in a notebook is to get the `Notebook` (which you have done), then pass the notebook's guid into `NoteStore.findNotesMetadata` (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata). This returns a `NotesMetadataList` which has a `notes` attribute which is a list of `NoteMetadata`. This struct has metadata like title and GUID but not the body. If you want the full information, you would pass the GUID into `NoteStore.getNote` (https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote).

Comment: it is seriously the most confusing documentation ever, even the general docs :( i'll keep pressing through though.

Comment: is there any way I can get a working example of this, unfortunately I am hitting bumps at every turn. Now im stuck at NotesMetadataResultSpec which findNotesMetadata relies on.... :(

Answer (score 0):

That API is one of the least Ruby things I've ever seen.  You have my condolences for trying to trudge through that :)

From the API docs, all I'm seeing that hangs off of that Evernote::EDAM::Type::Notebook class are #struct_fields and #validate, as far as instance methods go.  Perhaps that struct_fields has what you're looking for?

If that doesn't lead you anywhere, I'd suggest doing using something like Pry to help you troubleshoot the error.  I'd put a `binding.pry` statement on the second line and then explore the notebooks objects from there.